# Assign value to object based on condition

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, reduce

I am using the below method to assign value to my object(Team.Driver/Team.Codriver). This works fine but just wanted to know if I could improve this code via LINQ or other options.

```
public void MoveDriverCodriver(
    Team source, string sourceType, Team target, string targetType) 
{
    if (sourceType == "Driver")
    {
        if (targetType == "Driver")
        {
            target.Driver = source.Driver;
        }
        else
        {
            target.Codriver = source.Driver;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (targetType == "Driver")
        {
            target.Driver = source.Codriver;
        }
        else
        {
            target.Codriver = source.Codriver;
        }
    } 
}
```

Also second part is I want to update target Driver/Codriver details with the appropriate source. But I want to retain the id's of target Driver/Codriver.

```
class Driver
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Firstname { get; set; }
  public string Lastname { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Team
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Driver Driver { get; set; }
  public Driver Codriver { get; set; }
}
```

calling move operation.

```
Team team1 = new Team(); //Do some operation on team1
Team team2 = new Team(); //Do some operation on team2
MoveDriverCodriver(team1, "driver", team2, "codriver"); //Here I am trying to assign team1's driver to team2's codriver.
```

Comment: Linq is used to perform operations on collections. There is no collection here...

Comment: you can skip some else branches provided you exit early (`return;` after assigning)

Comment: The inner if `if(targetType == "Driver")` blocks are repeated in the outer if/else. You could make that a separate function to reduce code duplication. This question is really more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The logic behind looks wrong

Comment: Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection and also make your method generic for any types:

```
public void MoveDriverCodriver(
    object source, string sourceType, object target, string targetType) 
{
    if(targetType.ToLower() != "id")
    {
        var targetInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(targetType); 
        var sourceInfo = source.GetType().GetProperty(sourceType); 
        if (targetInfo != null && sourceInfo != null && targetInfo.PropertyType == sourceInfo.PropertyType) 
            targetInfo.SetValue(target, sourceInfo.GetValue(source));   
    }
}
```

Comment: he assigns 2 different properties, but maybe I am missing something

Comment: He assigns only one `targetType` property among two.

Comment: Although it's a big change, I think you changed it nicely :)

Comment: This works with bit modification. I have updated the above as follows:- 
            `var targetInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(targetType);
            var sourceInfo = source.GetType().GetProperty(sourceType);

            if (targetInfo != null && sourceInfo != null){
                targetInfo.SetValue(target, sourceInfo.GetValue(source));
            }`          Can I skip any property from copying i.e. I want the target driver/codriver id to remain as is just details have to be updated

Comment: @KavyaShetty, arguments checking is good thing, but at this case, you also should check, that types are same:  `if (targetInfo != null && sourceInfo != null && targetInfo.PropertyType == sourceInfo.PropertyType)`

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Can you please answer my question second part .Can I skip any property from copying i.e. I want the target driver/codriver id to remain as is just details have to be updated

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to restrict updating of id property?

Comment: Actually my targetType will always be Driver/Codriver. And id is a property of Driver/Codriver which I do not wish to copy. I  have updated my question for further understanding

Answer (score -1):

Whether you assign to `Driver` or `Codriver` is determined by `targetType`. So invert the checks and you can simplify the code:

```
public void MoveDriverCodriver(
    Team source, string sourceType, Team target, string targetType) 
{
    if (targetType == "Driver")
    {
        target.Driver = sourceType == "Driver" ? source.Driver : source.Codriver;
    }
    else
    {
        target.Codriver = sourceType == "Driver" ? source.Driver : source.Codriver;
    }
}
```

If you are using C# 7, you can then reduce the duplication further by using a local function:

```
public void MoveDriverCodriver(
    Team source, string sourceType, Team target, string targetType) 
{
    if (targetType == "Driver")
    {
        target.Driver = ChooseDriver();
    }
    else
    {
        target.Codriver = ChooseDriver();
    }

    DriverType ChooseDriver() => sourceType == "Driver" ? source.Driver : source.Codriver;
}
```

And again using C# 7, you could reduce it further by using tuples and a deconstruct:

```
public void MoveDriverCodriver(
    Team source, string sourceType, Team target, string targetType) 
{
    (target.Driver, target.Codriver) = targetType == "Driver"
        ? (ChooseDriver(), target.Codriver)
        : (target.Driver, ChooseDriver());

    DriverType ChooseDriver() => sourceType == "Driver" ? source.Driver : source.Codriver;
}
```

But I'd personally not go that far as you are now in the realms of having to assign an item's value back to itself just to save a few lines. So at this stage we've wondered away from simplifying into the realms of "clever" code, ie making it more complex just to make it shorter.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```
        public void MoveDriverCodriver(
Team source, string sourceType, Team target, string targetType)
    {
        target.Driver = targetType == "Driver" ? sourceType == "Driver" ? source.Driver : source.Codriver : null;
        target.Codriver = targetType != "Driver" ? sourceType == "Driver" ? source.Driver : source.Codriver : null;
    }
```

Comment: You changed the logic in so far that you always assign both `Driver` and `Codriver` what is not the case in the original code (I personally don't think that all if statements should be changed to ternary operators either)